Pushing text to a file in VBA that contains ", \, and > characters
I am trying to push text to a file that consists of the following string:
<exportfolder value="C:\placeholder_loc" />
In this, the "C:\placeholder_loc" is a different variable to feed in so I have split it into 3 strings for feeding in to the file.
I understand how to push the text via 'print' for each line, where I'm struggling is that VBA doesn't like characters like ", /, or > and wants to either autoformat with unwanted spaces or it just plain doesn't like the string. I'm using "" when I need the quotation mark, but when I try to add the " /> at the end of the string, it doesn't matter how I split it up, it either adds spaces or just gives me an error for incorrectly defined whatnot.
How do I push a string into VBA that contains VBA-recognized commands?
Right now the only successful attempt at this I have made is to start with a "starter" text file, open it, and change only the "placeholder_loc" portion of the text, which is really all I need out of this. It's extremely cludgy, but it works. I'd REALLY like to just write the whole file clean, which I'm currently able to do other than this one single line that has so many special characters in it that VBA gets confused on what's a string and what's a command.

Please edit your question to add the actual code you're trying to use.  Where are you getting the text from and how are you writing it?

This one-liner CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").OpenTextFile("C:\Temp\demo.txt", 2, True).Write "<exportfolder value=""" & "C:\blah\" & """ />" works fine for me

There are no special characters that VBA doesn't "like". The only thing you need to know is that if you need a double-quote character (") in a string, you need to double it so that the VBA compiler knows that you want to have a quote inside the string - else it will assume that you are ending a string.
Have a look:
debug.Print "<exportfolder value="C:\placeholder_loc" />"

will be marked as invalid syntax because the VBA compiler assumes that the string ends with value= - and the rest of the line makes no sense.
Instead, write
debug.Print "<exportfolder value=""C:\placeholder_loc"" />"

and you're good. The "" will tell the VBA compiler not to end the string but to put a quote character into the string. So the result will be
<exportfolder value="C:\placeholder_loc" />

Now the same rule applies if you want to have the placeholder coming from a variable:
Dim exportFolder as String
exportFolder = "C:\placeholder_loc"

debug.Print "<exportfolder value=""" & exportFolder & """ />"

value=""" is needed because the first two quotes tell VBA that you want a quote character inside the string, and the third quote tell that the string now ends.
As this is a little hard to read, you can also go for
Const quote = """"   ' A String with a single quote character
(...)
debug.Print "<exportfolder value=" & quote & exportFolder & quote & " />"

